# Runtime writer based on processor result in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I need help. I wish to change in runtime the itemWriter based on processor result

```
@Configuration
public class StepConfig {
@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public Step step(
    ItemReader<Sample> itemReader,
    ItemProcessor<Sample, Sample> beanProcessor,
    ItemWriter<Sample> itemWriter
) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("our step")
            .<Sample, Sample>chunk(1)
            .reader(itemReader)
            .processor(beanProcessor).listener(new ProcessorListener())
            .writer(itemWriter)
            .build();
}
```

}

My processor is a bean validation processor. If the validation succeed, I need a success writer. If it throws exception, I need to execute a exception writer.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I would keep it simple and use the item writer to write valid items, and an ItemProcessListener to report invalid items where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I did that:

1. I created 2 writers and tie them with a CompositeItemWriter
2. I pass a DTO with reference to the error for failure or/and the reference data processed with success.
3. The DTO is only for passing through processor to writers.
4. Each writer check if DTO has your respective data. If success data is there, work success data, otherwise return. If error data is there, work error data, otherwise return. CompositeItemWriter will always call all writers inside of it.

To be clear, in my case I had a reader that read information from a table. A pool of processors that processed the information, and at the end, populated a DTO. The DTO was only for take information from the processor to the CompositeItemWriter. The DTO had reference to two objects, one for success and another for error. Each writer checked its field on the DTO.

Maybe is possible to define [Spring Batch Flow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#conditionalFlow) for your case as well. It would be the most elegant way, but you have to study the documentation to see the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem after days!
First, I got a Classifier Writer. It decide which writer choose based in
my object property.

I highlight that before the classifier, I had to deal with the main problem, which was the BeanValidation processor.

As a bean validation processor, it works with just :

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Sample,Sample> validate() {
  return new BeanValidatingItemProcessor<>();
}
```

But I need to know if the validation will fail. So I tryed use a try/catch inside the method above and use the *.process(sample)* to see that. Inexplicably the method throws NPE.

I solved this making a bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Beans {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingItemProcessor<Sample> validatorBean() {
        return new BeanValidatingItemProcessor<Sample>();
    }
}
```

and injecting it in my processor. Finally it works.

Thank you all.